F:TAb->Ab the inclusion functor. F and has a right adjoint
Let $\mathrm{Ab}$ be the category of abelian groups, $\mathrm{TAb}$ the full subcategory of torsion abelian groups, and $i:\mathrm{TAb}\to \mathrm{Ab}$ the inclusion functor. I'm trying to show that $i$ and has a right adjoint.
I don't really have any idea what the right adjoint should look like. If anyone could give a description that would be great and I can try to show it's a right adjoint myself.

You could check that this functor preserves colimits?

Do you know how to go from an abelian group $A$ to a torsion group in a natural way?

See also here.

For a group $A$ you have $T(A)$ the subgroup of torsion elements of $A$, i.e. $x \in T(A) \iff \exists n>0$ such that $nx = 0$.
It is a subgroup since for $x$ and $y$ of indices $n$ and $m$, $$nm(x-y) = mn x - nm y= 0$$
(Thanks to @GeoffreyTrang for the correction of my awful non-proof).
One quick observation: if $R$ is a torsion group and $\phi:R \to A$, $\phi(R) \subset T(A)$ since $n\phi = \phi \circ (n\cdot -)$.
Now $T$ is a functor, just put $T(f) :T(A) \to T(B)$ induced by the restriction of $f$ to $T(A)$.
To exhibit the adjunction, we just set the unit:

 $$\eta = \mathrm{id}_{1_{\mathrm{TAb}}}: 1_{\mathrm{TAb}} \Rightarrow 1_{\mathrm{TAb}}= Ti$$

And the counit

 $\epsilon: iT \Rightarrow 1_{\mathrm{Ab}}$ defined by $\epsilon_A : T(A) \to A$ is the inclusion.

If you want to see the isomorphism in a more efficient way it is given by the map:

 $$ \phi \in \hom(R,T(A))   \mapsto  \epsilon_A \circ\phi \in \hom(R,A)$$


Appendix: This does not work for non abelian groups, indeed the torsion part of a group is not necessarily a subgroup. For example take two non-commutative idempotent, e.g. take $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ and the two unipotent matrices:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
We have $A^2 = I_2 = B^4$ but
$$BA = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
which cannot be unipotent since its characteristic (and minimal) polynomial is $X^2 - X - 1$ which roots are $\phi$ and $\bar{\phi}$ (golden number and its conjugate) which are not roots of the unity. So this element is not a torsion element.
However I don't know if the inclusion functor preserves colimits, if not there is no right adjoint to it. I don't even know if the full subcategory of torsion groups is cocomplete.

Consider $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. $(1,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ both have infinite order, but their sum is torsion. What is your $F$ here?

I'm so dumb let me delete this quickly :)

This should be better and correct now

Your proof that $T(A)$ is a subgroup is wrong. It looks like a part of the proof that the nilpotent elements of a commutative ring form an ideal. Torsion means $nx=0$, while nilpotent means $x^n=0$. Do not confuse "torsion" with "nilpotent".

Sorry I changed my notations from group with two commutative elements with notations for abelian groups for no reason and I confused myself without any reason let me correct that

Your correction is still wrong. Just because $nx=my=0$, it does not automatically follow that  $\max(n,m)x=0$ (if $n<m$) or $\max(n,m)y=0$ (if $n>m$). The correct proof should be that if $nx=my=0$, then $nm(x-y)=nmx-nmy=0$.

You are completely right it seems in the end I still confused nilpotent with torsion. Thanks for the reminder. I don't know I must be asleep or something

In the category of (possibly nonabelian) groups, the coproduct (free product) of any two nontrivial torsion groups is never a torsion group. Elements of finite order in $G*H$ must be conjugate to elements of finite order in $G$ or $H$.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I'm not sure that I follow the comments here, abelian groups are $\mathbb Z$-modules, which proves directly that subset of torsion elements of abelian group is subgroup. The proof as written now (I'm aware there were edits) proves exactly that. The only other crucial element is that image of torsion group ends in the torsion subgroup of codomain, which establishes the adjunction. I don't see that there is any problem.

@Ennar the proof in its globality was correct however the step showing that $T(A)$ was a subgroup was false, I then edited it :)
